# “C# grid control”: how to encode this in URL from SEO perspective?

Tags: seo, url, url-encoding

We are developing a WinForms grid control, and selling it thru our website worldwide. At the current stage of SEO works, we found that there are many popular search phrases with the "c#" word we can use ("c# grid control", etc).

But the sharp char (#) can't be encoded in URLs "as is" to have the maximal SEO effect for Google search. Here are possible choices to encode "c#":

1. "csharp".
2. "c sharp".
3. "c%23" (using hexadecimal codes).
4. No use of "#", so "c# grid" will look like "c-grid" in URL.

So the question is: what is the best way to reflect "c#" in URLs from SEO perspective? Are there more alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum indicator would be `c%23` but please note I used the word indicator, Google uses many factors to rank a page and in no way is this only the sole factor. You can rank pages without keywords in the URL, take these as an example:

- msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/hh341490.aspx
- www.csharp-station.com/tutorial.aspx
- www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm

Now with this said it does help to have keywords in the URL but remember its not the sole indicator and many on page elements can give Google this information, so forget the search engines for one moment and think how to construct your site the best way for your audience.

So my advice would to use a structor like so:

```
 /csharp/
 /csharp/programming-concepts/
 /csharp/development-for-absolute-beginners/
```

So, the best structor is one that you feel is best for your audience, using %23 could confuse your audience with the link.

Comment: Sure I know that a proper URL is not the sole factor to be in Google's top ;)

Comment: My research shows that webmasters tend to use the 4th option when choosing URLs for "c#" (used Google's inurl: operator for that), so I would use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the URL structure that reflects the page's content and purposes.
Friendly urls structure can improve your CTR in search engine's SERP, but not your ranking.
This parameter is aimed to help visitors to understand what is this page about, not to improve your position.

So, you may use any of structure examples you have suggest in your question. The main goal is to make it friendly to your visitors.